# Can we hide a field from composite adress without hidding it from the form?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

I added the field adresse: city to the form and 
I need to hide it from composite adress so as not to have it twice in the form. Is there any way to do this?
[image]
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

Hiding composite address fields on the form is no different than hiding regular form fields.

Use the control's [SetVisible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334266.aspx#BKMK_setVisible) property to hide it.

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute('address1_line1').controls.forEach(function(ctrl) {
    ctrl.setVisible(false);
});
```